# Deleting Nodes and Rels in a Neo4j Procedure

Tags: java, neo4j

I have drafted numerous Neo4j Procedures in Java.  I am running into an issue with one of them that I cannot seem to solve.  The purpose of this procedure is to "undo" some nodes and relationships that someone may have created in a prior procedure and now wants to undo.  Here is relevant code:

```
            while (Objects.nonNull(espnStack) && !espnStack.isEmpty()) {
            Node thisTestedNode = espnStack.pop();
            Stack<Node> stackOfBlockNodes = findEquityProperties.getAllBlockNodes(thisTestedNode);
            while (Objects.nonNull(stackOfBlockNodes) && !stackOfBlockNodes.isEmpty()) {
                Node thisBlockNode = stackOfBlockNodes.pop();
                Iterable<Relationship> allRels = thisBlockNode.getRelationships();
                for (Relationship thisRel : allRels) {
                    thisRel.delete();
                }
                thisBlockNode.delete();
            }
        }
```

There are a number of loops like this, where I have a node, I delete all the rels around the node, and then delete the node.  When I run this in debugger mode with unit tests, and follow the code line by line, it does exactly what it is supposed to do.  The node is found, the rels are identified, the rels are deleted one by one, then the node is deleted.  The issue is that when it ***returns*** from the procedure call, I get an error:

`org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Node with id 2 has been deleted in this transaction`

So, to be clear, the relevant portion of the unit test looks like this:

```
            Record record = session.run (
                    "MATCH (p) WHERE p.name = 'USP'\n" +
                            "MATCH (s) WHERE s.name = 'GSUB'\n" +
                             "CALL myProcedure.delete_equity(p,s) YIELD returnedObjects\n" +
                            "RETURN returnedObjects\n").single();
```

When I try and just run it in Neo4j Desktop with log.info() statements to see what is going on, and then I check the logs, it is as if no procedure call occurred at all.  It doesn't throw an error to the console.  It just acts as if nothing happened at all.

I believe what is happening is that the procedure is opening a transaction, but 'something' prevents the transaction from being committed and then any changes that were made are being rolled back as if nothing happened.  But I cannot figure out what the issue is.  I tried doing a Transaction.commit() after I delete the nodes in the procedure, but that throws an error saying that you cannot commit within a procedure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you returning from the proc as `returnedObjects`? if there is a node in there, cypher cannot access it it anymore.

Comment: Just a string telling the user that their nodes have been deleted.  I am going to try and revise it so that instead of deleting each node one at a time, I am just going to add them to a HashSet and then just before return, pop them from the set and delete them.  Maybe (maybe) I am somehow trying to delete a node that has already been deleted, but I don't think so, because I tested it on a simple fact pattern and debugged it line by line and that didn't seem to be the issue.